# Create a line between div tags after Drag and Drop JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div tag box in the middle of a page with a lot of div tags around it. I want to be able to drag any of outside div tags to the box in the middle then the div will return to is its normal position but a line to be created to connect the div tag to the box in the middle.

```
  $(function() {
      $(".student").draggable({
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            return !event;
        }
    });
    $("#class").droppable();
});
```

I have had a go at it here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j0yaoLL/)

I managed to get the boxes to drag to the middle box or simply return to their normal positions. I am new to Jquery, Please can you advice me what to do next?

Comment: I recommend you try using jsPlumb (Comunity edition) || vis.js || jQuery connections || or any graph library

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/9j0yaoLL/1/

Comment: @RohitTotala jsPlumb is not free is it?

Comment: @Mohammad thank you but i want it to create a link and return to normal position instead of placing it inside the box

Comment: jsPlumb Community Edition is free, and with some search on source target connection in jsPlumb, I guess you can achieve what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/wGjDm/7/ , this will help you, look at `jsPlumb.connect() method`